# Customising the increments in an org-mode timestamp

Tags: org-agenda, time-date

When I create an appointment in org-agenda I make use of timestamps. The item is created with today's date and time and I then place my cursor on the date and time respectively and use <kbd>S-up</kbd> or <kbd>S-down</kbd> to increase or decrease the time until I get to the time I need. I see that time increments by default are 5 minutes. I would prefer it to be 30 minutes. Can can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure you are pressing *CONTROL*- {up, down} to change the times? Might you be pressing *SHIFT*-{up, down} instead? This does not affect the question and answer, but it might confuse people reading this.

Comment: Mea Culpa. I meant to say Shift-up and Shift-down. Apologies.

Comment: OK - thanks! I edited the question and the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>S-up</kbd> and <kbd>S-down</kbd> are bound to `org-shiftup` and `org-shiftdown`. On timestamps, these call `org-timestamp-up` and `org-timestamp-down` respectively. These methods use the variable `org-time-stamp-rounding-minutes`:

> Number of minutes to round time stamps to.
>
> These are two values, the first applies when first creating a time stamp.
>
> The second applies when changing it with the commands ‘S-up’ and ‘S-down’.
>
> When changing the time stamp, this means that it will change in steps
>   of N minutes, as given by the second value.

So we can change the second value to `30`:

```
(setf (elt org-time-stamp-rounding-minutes 1)
      30)
```

And now these methods will move by 30 minutes[1].

[1] It will move to the nearest multiple of this value; <kbd>S-up</kbd> once on `<2019-10-09 Wed 06:27>` will move it to `<2019-10-09 Wed 06:30>`; calling it again gives `<2019-10-09 Wed 07:00>`.

Comment: When you say `C-up` and `C-down`, you really mean `S-up` and `S-down`, don't you? See the doc string of the variable that you quoted.

Comment: @NickD Neither `S-up` nor `S-down` is not bound on my version of org, and the OP in the question says they're using `C-up` and `C-down`, so I used the Ctrl versions in the answer.

Comment: What version is that? AFAIK, `org-shiftup` and `org-shiftdown` have always been bound to `S-up` and `S-down` (hence the function names: these settings are ancient).

Comment: I should add that these settings are the default on GUI emacs, but even on console emacs, they are supposed to work: see the doc string for `org-support-shift-select`.

Comment: On the computer I'm at now, which is running a GUI emacs, I have Org 9.1.9.

Comment: 9.1.9 org.el, line 19535ff: `(org-defkey org-mode-map [(shift up)]          'org-shiftup)`. Are you *sure* `S-up` is not bound to `org-shiftup`? What does `C-h w RET org-shiftup RET` say?

Comment: Oh, damn everything. I always read `S-` as _super_, not _shift_. Yeah, it seems to be on shift-up.

Comment: OK - can you please fix the answer? We have to assume that the OP made a mistake.